# Standalone current limiting circuit for Ultracap banks

Tags: mosfet, high-current, supercapacitor

I've been experimenting with ultracaps for a while now and I have a very specific problem:

I use the ultracapacitors to compensate for line inductances and general power filtering. When I install a capacitor (16F to 33F) in a vehicle (14Vdc) I obviously have to precharge them to avoid the huge inrush current. However this is not a permanent solution because when the battery is disconnected for service the capacitor would discharge and would have to be recharged again.

My plan is to use a high power resistor to limit the current until the voltage has reached a certain level. Then a Mosfet/SSR/Relay will short the resistor, connecting the bank to the system.

Now my question is, what is the simplest most robust (not cheapest) solution that can be left unattended. 
Obviously once the system is charged I want the lowest possible current draw and resistance.

Maybe an opamp as an comparator switching a mosfet? How do I avoid the ohmic region?

Heres the datasheet for one of my typical caps:
https://cz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/257/2_7_100F_ds_3001959_datasheet-1517387.pdf

Comment: How fast or how long the charging should take? Or what is the current you want to charge at?

Comment: a time constant of under one minute would be nice. I do not want to exceed 10A, or whatever the resistor can handle. ESR of one cap is around 10mOhm, I usually have 6 or 7 in series and 1-4 in parallel. I want a circuit for one with one parallel and 7 series. So 70mOhm in total.

Comment: Define the current limit  that you wish to use.  33F stores 3.4kW-seconds or 14.2 W per Amp-second. So charge time is controlled by your current limit of fuse.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 around 10A for now. I need a circuit, I can scale the other components accordingly once I have that.

Comment: 10A will take 45 s to charge 3.4kW

Comment: Yeah okay but I need a circuit that will turn on a mosfet once a set voltage is reached.

Comment: You need a 10A battery charger kit, There is no trivial solution.

Comment: You can charge it up with a 50W head light , which takes a minute or so 3400W/50

Comment: 14V feeding a 10A current means 140W power (when cap has been discharged). There are two ways to approach a solution for charging the cap. One is to dissipate this 140W, through a lightbulb, resistors, or transistors. If you use resistors or transistors to dissipate this power, they _must_ be adequately rated. Even a few seconds of 140W power on an underrated resistor can cause failure, fire, or permanent damage. The other approach is to chop your power supply with a current limiting buck regulator. Less heat is involved, but the circuitry is considerably more complex. Think about your options

Comment: The value of the resistor is not my concern. I need a circuit that gives my logic high to turn on a mosfet or relay once a set voltage is reached.

Comment: No, I mean a Mosfet whose Source and Drain are on either end of the resistor, shorting it.  I only need the resistor to charge it.

Comment: You really seem to have your heart set on using resistance, but just FYI a switched mode constant current circuit would do a better job of charging your cap and could still be bypassed at an arbitrary voltage.  It's also worth noting that having caps automatically discharge is a typical safety feature in high power capacitor setups.  If your intent is to leave the caps charged, it would be wise to take care isolating them and potentially take other precautions.

Answer (score 2):

A 12V 50 W high beam+low beam bulb in series will limit current to 2.4A as the Cap charges up. dt= 33F * 12V   / 2.4A = 165 seconds. The bulb will draw more current as it dims below visibility and speed up a bit.

Comment: I have not thought about that. Good idea. But when the Capacitor has reached sufficent voltage, how do I short the bulb? Like with a relay or a mosfet. I need a circuit that gives a logic signal once a voltage, say 13V, is reached. Im thinking a voltage divider with an opamp maybe?

Comment: yes anything like that or a transistor with <0.7 Vbe with base R to limit current and NPN to bulb on low side  and Collector goes low when charging. and pulled up to Vdd when ready to bypass using a 10A relative and low inductive litz wire to load from cap and gnd.

Comment: Flowx... Just as Motor Off current burns out relay contacts, so do Cap charge ON currents, so ensure you check discharge contact ratings and consider a 25A relay so 25A*70 mOhm = 1.75V  @Justme  70A? you sure ?